create new column to divide values by specific row value
I want to take a source data set, filter it based on some criteria, then do a calculation on each value (dividing each gpt_date’s value by the 2nd gpt_date’s value). The expected output is a new table via blank query that outputs the new calculated values for each gpt_date. For context, this is taking daily discount factors from an interest rate curve, and rolling them forward one business day in time. It’s a common usage for financial valuations.
I have been attempting to build this in my Power BI report through Power Query, but have been struggling to get the code to work (still very new at Power Query M). I would greatly appreciate assistance as hopefully the example will give me understanding of how to do similar code in the future.
You can see the below actions I take on the initial data set. I first need to filter for the right value to use per gpt_date by taking the maximum Value for each gpt_date set. Then, I want to divide each of these Values by the 2nd gpt_date’s Value (in this case, 10/28/2024 gpt_date). The last step is to output this new data set into a blank query, excluding 10/25/2025 gpt_date as it’s no longer applicable.



Action
Description




Step1 =
Filter for max Value per gpt_date (since two Values exist per gpt_date in initial data set)


Step2 =
Divide each gpt_date's Step1 Value by 2nd gpt_date's Step1 Value


Step3 =
Output Step2 Value for each gpt_date in new table (blank query)






Initial Data Set





gpt_date
Value


10/25/2024
1


10/25/2024
0.0426


10/28/2024
0.9995267787


10/28/2024
0.0426


10/31/2024
0.9991749239


10/31/2024
0.04245


11/1/2024
0.9990617737


11/1/2024
0.04224


11/6/2024
0.9984769111


11/6/2024
0.04221


11/8/2024
0.9982427957


11/8/2024
0.04221


11/11/2024
0.9978917255


11/11/2024
0.04221






Output Data Set





gpt_date
Value_rolled


10/28/2024
1


10/31/2024
0.9996479786


11/1/2024
0.9995347749


11/6/2024
0.9989496354


11/8/2024
0.9987154091


11/11/2024
0.9983641728




Can you please clarify the second step? Use a mathematical equation if you can, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Your Output Data Set doesn't seem to make sense mathematically given your input. Please clarify.

The output from my query doesn’t match exactly what you specified in your request, but I’ve added comments to the code to make it easy for you to adjust if my code doesn’t fully meet your needs:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    ChangedType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"gpt_date", type datetime}, {"Value", type number}}),

    // Group by 'gpt_date' and calculate the Max (or Min) for each date - chjange as required
    GroupedData = Table.Group(ChangedType, {"gpt_date"}, 
        {
            {"Value", each List.Min([Value]), type number}
        }
    ),

 // Add Index Column starting from 1
    AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(GroupedData, "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),

    // Add Previous Value column, offset by one row
    AddPreviousValue = Table.AddColumn(AddIndex, "Previous Value", 
        each if [Index] = 1 then null else AddIndex[Value]{[Index] - 2}),
    
    // Calculate the Ratio (Min Value / Previous Min Value)
    AddRatio = Table.AddColumn(AddPreviousValue, "Value_rolled", 
        each if [Previous Value] = null then null else [Value] / [Previous Value], 
        type number),
    
    // Remove Index and Previous Min Value columns if they are not needed
    RemoveExtraColumns = Table.RemoveColumns(AddRatio,{"Index", "Previous Value", "Value"})
    
in
    RemoveExtraColumns


Thank you very much for this post. I was able to utilize your code to meet my needs. Note that my post specified that each gpt_date value is divided by the 2nd gpt_date value, not the 2nd prior value (absolute 2nd row, not relative minus 2nd row). So I amended your code to use "AddIndex{1}[Value]"
